# Mad lib Python, why the loop below is not working properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7

UPDATE: following the 1st answer, the top code delivers the intended outputs.

I just started practicing python 2.7. In this mad lib exercise, I were asked to take a string replace any NOUN/VERB according to the random functions and return back the output string after doing this replacement. I am stuck at the bold line "i = space_pos + 1", I thought that after identifying the space/' ' position, i should run the loop again from the next position after the space.

Working code:

```
import random

def random_verb():
   return random.choice(["run","kayak"])

def random_noun():
   return random.choice(["sofa","llama"])

def word_transformer(word):
   if word == "NOUN":
      return random_noun()
   elif word == "VERB":
      return random_verb()
   else:
      return word

def process_madlib(mad_lib):
   # Split the string into words
   words = mad_lib.split() 
   # Apply a transformation to each word
   transformed = map(word_transformer, words)
   # Join the transformed words
   return " ".join(transformed) 

#test-output 
test_string_1 = "This is a good NOUN to use when you VERB your food"
test_string_2 = "I'm going to VERB to the store and pick up a NOUN or 
                   two."
print process_madlib(test_string_1)
print process_madlib(test_string_2)

#old non working version 
from random import randint

def random_verb():
    random_num = randint(0, 1)
    if random_num == 0:
        return "run"
    else:
       return "kayak"

def random_noun():
    random_num = randint(0,1)
    if random_num == 0:
       return "sofa"
    else:
       return "llama"

def word_transformer(word):
    if word == "NOUN":
        return random_noun()
    elif word == "VERB":
        return random_verb()
    else:
        return word

def process_madlib(mad_lib):
    processed = ""
    i = 0
    while (i < len(mad_lib)):
      space_pos = mad_lib.find(' ', i)                #find space_pos: 4 
      word = mad_lib[i:space_pos]                     #ex: This
      processed += word_transformer(word)             #check "This" VS 
      i = space_pos +1 #This is the problem line      #NOUN/VERB          
                                               #start loop after the space, 
                                               #at pos:5 to check new word                                   
    return processed                           #(is)



test_string_1 = "This is a good NOUN to use when you VERB your food"
print process_madlib(test_string_1)
```

Comment: First, please format your code.

Comment: Thanks @DYZ for pointing this out, just edited it :)

Comment: Your first function can (and probably should) be rewritten as `return random.choice(["run","kayak"])`. Same with the second function.

Comment: You can't format text in code. Edited to fix

Comment: @TrooperZ added your changes, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is hard to follow and quite un-pythonic. Consider using the Python power tools: splitting, list comprehension, and joining.

```
def process_madlib(mad_lib):
    # Split the string into words
    words = mad_lib.split() 
    # Apply a transformation to each word
    transformed = [word_transformer(word) for word in words]
    # Join the transformed words
    return " ".join(transformed)
```

The second line of the function body can be further rewritten as a mapping:

```
    transformed = map(word_transformer, words)
```

Finally, the whole function could be implemented as a one-liner:

```
def process_madlib(mad_lib):
    return " ".join(map(word_transformer, mad_lib.split()))
```

Comment: Super @DYZ, Thanks!!! i see that i am missing a lot of the built in tools. I walked through your answer and it works perfectly. I will get the code updated above :)

Comment: If you do not have further questions, you should accept the answer. If you still do have questions, you should update the original post.